# Chrome Autofill Credit Card not working

Tags: google-chrome

Autofilling Credit Card number in Chrome have never worked for me. I do not know what is wrong.
If it depends on the page, could you then provide a page, where it works for you?

I'm using Google Chrome 15.0.860.0 canary and Mac OS X 10.7.1

Comment: I've never auto-filled a credit card number for security reasons, but surely this is something you don't want?

Comment: Agreed-it's one of those things that you _don't_ want to work, like Skynet and almost everything in Torchwood.

Comment: Okay maybe not autofilling, but the option for Chrome to put in it? And why even have the option to autofill credit cards, if it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag to enable it. Here is how to turn it on:

- Enter `chrome://flags/` in the URL
- Look for **Enable new Autofill heuristics**
- Click `Enable`
- Restart Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is an unofficial form attribute that IE6 started called Autocomplete, and the web designer could be set to keep it off. Another reason could be that https pages usually don't allow autofill at all. Could either of those be true? Has it worked in previous versions?